# ADT unexpected argument

Tags: apache-flex, adt, flex4.6, ane

I'm trying to build ANE and need to specify `-platformsdk path_to_ios_sdk` argument. But I'm getting `unexpected argument -platformsdk`. Moreover I've tried to run ADT with any other parameters and they don't work. Why?

adt -connect xxx as example:
[image]

Is there anything I'm doing in a wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use the platformsdk option when building the ANE but when building your application using an ANE. The option is invalid for a native extension build.

When you are building your iOS application you should specify it as below:

```
adt -package \
    -target ipa-test \
    -provisioning-profile /path_to_provisioning_profile/Provisioning_Profile.mobileprovision \
    -storetype pkcs12 \
    -keystore /path_to_certificate/certificate.p12 \
    -storepass xxxxx \
    myApp.ipa \
    application_xml_file.xml \
    application_swf.swf \
    -platformsdk PATH_TO_SDK
```

When you are building your ANE you should make sure you have shared libraries enabled and specify the frameworks your extension is using in the iOS platform options xml file.

```
adt -package \
    -storetype pkcs12 -keystore /path_to_certificate/certificate.p12 -storepass xxxxx \
    -target ane extension.ane extension.xml \
    -swc extenion_as_library.swc \
    -platform iPhone-ARM -platformoptions platform.xml -C PATH_TO_IOS_LIB . \
    -platform default -C PATH_TO_DEFAULT_LIB .
```

Comment: actually I've found the same option in Flash Builder project settings where I can set iOS SDK path. Guess it works like -platformsdk

Comment: Yes the recent version of FB has this option and is just a UI for the platformsdk option. But this is again only for building an application, not the ANE. 

Cheers